# SQL ALTER TABLE DEFAULT NULL still inserts 0

Tags: php, mysql

I have an `ALTER TABLE` query in my php file where the name of the table is based on the $name variable.

e.g. `$table = "Scores: ".$name;`

I have substituted the `$table` variable into my `INSERT` statement and verifies that it does indeed work.

The *scores_name* table consists of integer fields (smallint), when a `$POST` value is empty, the number which is inserted into the table is 0 (by default obviously).

However, when a certain condition is met (in a non-empty field), the value for that particular row is intentionally set to be 0.

There are times when the `$POST` value should be empty, and therefore I want that particular row to be blank, so hence when it inserts as 0 instead of this, this causes obvious confusion.

The following is my alter statement, there are 5 game rows, so this alter query is triggered when the column for that particular game is empty:

```
if($game1(empty))
{
   $query = "ALTER TABLE `$table` MODIFY COLUMN `game1` SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL";
   $result = mysql_query($query) or die (' ' . mysql_error() );
}
```

No mysql error is returned, so therefore I'm assuming the `ALTER` statement is completing properly, however why is it still inserting 0, despite being modified to default to NULL?

Is there really no way to store a blank value within an integer-based table?

Comment: What do you mean by 'blank'?

Comment: what is you insert command?

Comment: As far as I know you can't have a "blank" value in an int column

Comment: @Strawberry, as in display nothing at all in that field.

Comment: Do you try to insert as follows `INSERT INTO yourtable (game1) VALUES (' ')?

Comment: @user3577618: You posted with used `ALTER` and questioning about why `insert` failed in a way. Unless you show what your `insert` statement is, every one will assume wild.

Comment: $thequery = "INSERT IGNORE INTO $table (scoreNo, game1, game2, game3...etc) 
             VALUES ('$scoreno', '$outcome1', '$outcome2', '$outcome3'...etc')";

By etc I mean imagine that it is game 4, game 5, outcome 4, outcome5 for sake of length.

Comment: You should consider redesign your application to a proper normalization. Use of DDL statements in a runtime application is always a bad idea.

Comment: @user3577618: What is the output of `echo $outcome1` ?

Comment: @Ravinder there is no output, echo does not print anything as when 
I submitted the form I did not fill it in, if I do fill it in, the value echo'd is the number that I filled in

Comment: @user3577618 this is a basic debugging strategy: to echo out a concatenated string (this time a sql statement). And it shoud print something in the line `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` It would be better to leave the old deprecated mysql_* functions behind and move to mysqli or PDO and prepared statements with placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRiMARY KEY,x INT DEFAULT NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (x) VALUES (0),(''),(' '),(NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table (id) VALUES (0),(''),(' '),(NULL);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT);

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+------+
| id | x    |
+----+------+
|  1 |    0 |
|  2 |    0 |
|  3 |    0 |
|  4 | NULL |
|  5 | NULL |
|  6 | NULL |
|  7 | NULL |
|  8 | NULL |   
|  9 | NULL |
+----+------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Deleting tables will be problematic for me, is there any way I can just alter it without doing so? Btw I'm just doing php code using the mysql_query function, so I'm not using that syntax.

Comment: @user3577618: this solution is not suggesting you to drop table. but try usage of keyword `default` when you want to skip invalid input data from user.

Comment: It's demonstrating a whole bunch of things - none of which is about deleting your own tables. Stop. Step away from the terminal. Grab a nice warm beverage. And then come back and take some time to digest the example provided above.

Comment: @user3577618 Take a look at the INSERT statements and the result in the tyble! Especially the first and last one.

Comment: How about when I create the actual table and initialize the fields e.g.
"game1 SMALLINT, game2 SMALLINT". I instead do "game1 SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL, game2 SMALLINT DEFAULT NULL"?

Comment: Or should I do "game1 SMALLINT DEFAULT (two single quotes) , game2 SMALLINT DEFAULT (two single quotes) " ?

Answer (score 1):

> *There are times when the $POST value should be empty, and therefore I want that particular row to be blank, so hence when it inserts as 0 instead of this, this causes obvious confusion.*

With the statement, I understand that you don't want to fill values into column but the `default` values as defined at column creation.

Possible ways to insert `default` values into columns are:

1. Do not use the column in the query while `INSERT`ing.
2. `IF` a condition is satisfied then use `DEFAULT` in place of value
   for the column in question.

**Example**:
Say, your table is defined like the following:

```
create table tbl_so_q23869976( si smallint default null, col2 varchar(10) );
```

Let us see, how we can set defaults into `si` column.

**Case 1**: All is well, then:

```
$sql = "insert into tbl_so_q23869976( si, col2 ) values ( ?, ? )";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( @sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 'ds', 6, 'Ravin' ); // use proper variables in place of values
```

**Case 2.1**: If something is not matched, then:

```
/* use with 'default' to insert defaults */
$sql = "insert into tbl_so_q23869976( si, col2 ) values ( default, ? )";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( @sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 's', 'Ravin' ); // use proper variables in place of values
```

**Case 2.2**: If something is not matched, then:

```
/*just omit the column name into which you want to insert defaults */
$sql = "insert into tbl_so_q23869976( col2 )  values ( ? )";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( @sql );
$stmt->bind_param( 's', 'Ravin' ); // use proper variables in place of values
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very confused, I have never used mysqli before, is there a mysql equivalent to just skip inserting values that are null? Unfortunately this code makes absolutely no sense to me. I just want to skip the column (make it blank), if a variable has been left blank on submit, even setting it to NULL as the default still prints 0 no matter what. As long as the empty field is set to LITERALLY ANYTHING but 0 I will be happy. Also acceptable would be if it will set the field to a number, but display it as blank when you output the table (similar to zerofill, changing representation)